# Is the line graph of expander graph is also expander?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[Expander graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph) is a sparse graph that has strong connectivity.

Expander graphs can be definied by 3 equivalent ways:  edge expansion, vertex expansion, and  spectral expansion.

My question is the line graph of expander graph is also expander?

My approach to this problem is that the edge expansion of graph $G$ could be equal to the  vertex expansion of its line graph $L(G)$, and vice versa, but I'm not sure.

Any idea will be useful!